# trac and svn (tortoise) - "Issue Tracker Plugin" - ( yes, yet another svn and trac question)

Tags: tortoisesvn, bug-tracking, trac

I would like to be able to "get information from the issue tracker" as described in the section "Getting Information from the Issue Tracker" at: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html  (display a dlg box to the user when they start a commit action in svn so they can choose form a list of issues assigned to them)

I have tried finding information about a COM plugin for tortoisesvn, but have been unsuccessful in actually finding one.  There are many links to pages, etc stating what is possible, but I do not want to write one and am hoping one exists.

Can anyone shed some light on this or point me to a plugin for my client?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are example implementations of IBugTraqProvider in the contrib/ directory of the TSVN source. One's in ATL; it runs an EXE, passing (among other things) a temporary filename for the provider to write a commit message to. That EXE should talk to your issue tracker.

The other's in C#; it displays some mocked up data, but could be extended as required.

There are a couple of others: [Gurtle](http://code.google.com/p/gurtle/) talks to Google Code; there's one for Trac [here](http://tracexplorer.devjavu.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I don't have time right now to look at it but I think that is what I was hoping for. EDIT I did try that tool out, and it worked fairly well.